# Turn a {{}} (dplyr double curly braces) interpolation into a string

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's assume I have the following R function:

```r
library(tidyverse)

f <- function(.df, .var) {
  .df %>% ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = {{ .var }})) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle({{ .var }})
}

f(mtcars, hp)
#> Error in list2(..., title = title, subtitle = subtitle, caption = caption, : object 'hp' not found
f(mtcars, qsec)
#> Error in list2(..., title = title, subtitle = subtitle, caption = caption, : object 'qsec' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

How do I access the actual string that `.var` takes to use when creating a title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the double curly braces, which evaluate the variable in context of the data frame, you need to use `enquo` to get a string:

```r
library(tidyverse)

f <- function(.df, .var) {
  .df %>% ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = {{ .var }})) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(enquo(.var))
}

f(mtcars, hp)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `deparse` + `substitute` to change unquoted value to a string which can be used in `ggtitle`.

```
library(ggplot2)

f <- function(.df, .var) {
  title <- deparse(substitute(.var))
  
  .df %>% ggplot(aes(x = wt, y = {{ .var }})) +
    geom_point() +
    ggtitle(title)
}

f(mtcars, hp)
```

[image]

Comment: How does this compare to using `enquo`?

Comment: I haven't used `enquo` enough to know about it. Additionally, both `deparse` and `substitute` are base R functions.